# If a generating function for $f(n)$ is rational, $f(n)$ cannot be more than exponential.

Tags: generating-functions

If I have a generating function for $f(n)$ defined by

$g(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)x^n=\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$,

where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials and $Q(x)$ is not the zero function, how could I show that $f(n)$ is not more than exponential?

Comment: Think in terms of partial fractions and geometric series expansions.

Comment: We may assume $Q(0) \ne 0$.  The radius of convergence is the least absolute value of a zero of $Q$.  What does the root test say about $f(n)$?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 4):

1. Since $Q(0)\ne0$, $|Q(z)|\geqslant a$ for every $z$ in a neighborhood of $0$, say for every $|z|\leqslant\varepsilon$, for some $a\gt0$ and $\varepsilon\gt0$.
2. Since $P$ is continuous, $|P(z)|\leqslant b$ for every $|z|\leqslant\varepsilon$, for some finite $b$.
3. For every $n$,
   $$
   f(n)=\frac1{2\mathrm i\pi}\oint\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\frac{\mathrm dz}{z^{n+1}},
   $$
   where the integral is over the circle of equation $|z|=\varepsilon$, whose length is $2\pi\varepsilon$.
4. In particular,
   $$
   |f(n)|\leqslant\frac1{2\pi}2\pi\varepsilon\frac{b}a\frac1{\varepsilon^{n+1}}=cK^n,
   $$
   with $c=b/a$ and $K=1/\varepsilon$.

Comment: Here we go, you used the idea of the nth derivative of a function. Using the Cauchy's formula for the nth derivative.

Comment: @Mhenni: Sorry but I fail to see how your comment applies to my answer (which uses no *derivative*).

Comment: What you used is the Cauchy formula for the nth derivative of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ at the point $x=0$ divide bu $n!$. It is the formula $ f(n)=\frac{1}{n!}{\left(\frac{P(0)}{Q(0)}\right)}^{(n)} = \frac{1} {2\pi i} \int_C \frac { P(z) }{ Q(z) }\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}} $.

Answer (score 0):

If you look backward to your problem you see that $f(n)$ is nothing, but the nth derivative of your rational polynomial $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ divided by $ n! $. I refer you to my Ph.D thesis (section 6.2.1) which covers the topic of finding the nth derivative of any rational polynomial. In other words you get a closed form formula for the nth derivative which may help you to conclude you assertion:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm/edit?hl=en_GB&pli=1

Comment: Once you have the partial fraction decomposition (as in your thesis), you hardly need explicit formulas for the derivatives; the standard geometric-series classification (as in anon's comment) is a much easier way of seeing the same thing.

Comment: My point was to give him an idea to prove his assertion by exploiting the nth derivative of his rational polynomial.